# How to total rows in array type column in Spark Dataframe. Possibly through posexplode reversal

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe of the format below:

```
 df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,1,1,  [1,2,3,4,5]),(1,1,2,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,1,3,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,1,4,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,2,5,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,2,6,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,2,7,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,3,8,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,3,9, [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,3,10, [1,2,3,4,5])], ["acc", "sub-acc", "item", "values"])`
```

The values column is an array of doubles. I need to ***subtotal*** the values column for ***acc*** and ***sub-acc***

In pseudo code it would look like something like this:

`df.groupby('acc,'sub-acc').sum('values')`

But the resulting `sum(values)` should still be an array where each element is is a sum of corresponding elements from each row.

I was able to produce the sample result using the following code:

```
df_1 = df.select('acc','sub-acc', "item", F.posexplode_outer(df.values))
df_1 = df_1.groupby('acc','sub-acc', 'pos').sum('col').withColumnRenamed('sum(col)', 'values')
df_1.sort('acc','sub-acc','pos').groupby('acc','sub-acc').agg(F.collect_list('values').alias('values')).toPandas()
```

The result should be like this:

```
> acc   sub-acc values

0   1   3   [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]

1   1   1   [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
```

I am worried that code I am showing above will not work on real size data. In the real example the values column will have 10,000 values in each array and there will be several million rows in the dataframe, so I am not sure the order of operations will be guaranteed even on sorted dataframe due to parallel processing. Essentially, I need to find a reliable way to reverse the result of posexplode after I've summarized each value. Or possibly there is a better way. Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is difficult to find examples for complex array transformations in Spark. I've referred example from [aggregate official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html).

To make it work, I've changed the LongType in the dataframe to IntegerType.

```py
schema = StructType([StructField('acc', IntegerType(), True), StructField('sub-acc', IntegerType(), True), StructField('item', IntegerType(), True), StructField('values', ArrayType(IntegerType(), True), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,1,1,  [1,2,3,4,5]),(1,1,2,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,1,3,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,1,4,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,2,5,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,2,6,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,2,7,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,3,8,  [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,3,9, [1,2,3,4,5]), 
(1,3,10, [1,2,3,4,5])], schema= schema)
```

To make it generic, compute length of "values" array. I guess, in sample, you've given 5 element array; but in reality it is of variable length.

```py
values_len = len(df.select("values").limit(1).collect()[0]["values"])
```

Initialise an accumulator as a zero-element-array as initial value of element-wise addition:

```py
acc = F.array([F.lit(0) for _ in range(values_len)])

[Out]:
array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Group by "acc" and "sub-acc" and collect "values" as an array of array:

```py
df = df.groupBy(["acc", "sub-acc"]).agg(F.collect_list("values").alias("values_arr"))
```

Finally, perform element-wise addition of "values_arr":

```py
df.select(F.aggregate("values_arr", acc, lambda a, x: F.array([a[i]+x[i] for i in range(values_len)])).alias("values_sum")).show(truncate=False)

[Out]:
+------------------+
|values_sum        |
+------------------+
|[3, 6, 9, 12, 15] |
|[4, 8, 12, 16, 20]|
|[3, 6, 9, 12, 15] |
+------------------+
```